# run find command and email results

Tags: linux, bash, email, sendmail

I want to use a find command in order to obtain files older than 8640 min and send the result in a email body. I used this script that makes use of a file - ATTACH_FILE - containing the results of the find command:

```
#!/bin/sh
ATTACH_FILE="/pub/email_attach.txt"
WORK_DIR="/pub/"
rm -f $ATTACH_FILE
find $WORK_DIR -maxdepth 1 -name '*x.rsd' -type f -daystart -mmin +8640 -exec echo {} >> $ATTACH_FILE \;

if [ ! -z $ATTACH_FILE ]; then
    FILESIZE=$(stat -c%s "$ATTACH_FILE" 2>> getLatestErr.log)
    echo $ATTACH_FILE "size $FILESIZE bytes"
    if [ $FILESIZE -gt 0 ]; then
       cat $ATTACH_FILE | mail -s "Test "$TODAY mmm@server.com
    fi
fi
```

How can I get the same result by putting a message in the body of the email without using the auxiliary file ATTACH_FILE ?

Comment: Capture the find output in a variable: `FILELIST=$(find ...)`, no output redirection; use `FILELIST` in the place of `ATTACH_FILE` in the remaining code, remove lines dealing with the file. Replace the FILESIZE calculation and check with `if [ -n "${FILELIST}" ]; then`

Comment: @Tom Regner thanks for your respone. If I use FILE_LIST=$( find $WORK_DIR -maxdepth 1 -name '*x.rsd' -type f -daystart -mmin +8640 ); I have all items in a single row like file1 file2 .... How can I divide them on several lines?

Comment: Did you use one of the provided solutions? Are there further problems? A bit of feedback's nice :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on my comment above:

Assign to an array variable and use `printf` to separate the found items with a newline character:

```
#!/bin/bash
WORK_DIR="/pub/"

FILE_LIST=($(find $WORK_DIR -maxdepth 1 \
    -name '*x.rsd' -type f \
    -daystart -mmin +8640 ))

if [ -n "${FILE_LIST[0]}" ]; then
   printf '%s\n' "${FILE_LIST[@]}" | mail -s "Test "$TODAY mmm@server.com
fi
```

I exchanged `/bin/sh` with `/bin/bash`, as the question is tagged with `[bash]`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `-e` option to `mail`. That tells it not to do anything if the input is empty.

```
find $WORK_DIR -maxdepth 1 -name '*x.rsd' -type f -daystart -mmin +8640 -print | mail -e -s "Test "$TODAY mmm@server.com
```